# how to set image to height 100% in specific width in google chrome with CSS?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I wrote this css (below), and works properly in firefox, but when I use Chrome, the problem happened, the chrome assumed that "height : 100%" is tobe 100% of the real image. I want it 100% just from the width that I've set.

`.prof-img{
    width:150px;
    height:100%;
}`

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 0):

"100% height" is inherited from parent elements, therefore you need to declare it all the way up the tree.

```
body, html {
   height:100%
}

.prof-img {
   width:150px;
   height:100%;
}
```

Comment: thanks, but I set like .prof-img { width:150px; min-height:0; } it works in both ;)

Answer (score 0):

I use this and works perfectly for both browser

```
.prof-img {
   width:150px;
   min-height:0;
}
```

fixed ;)